# Oracle SQL - Cumulative sum over time based on groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table that looks like:

| id | date | amount | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-1 | 2 | g1 |
| 2 | 2022-1 | 5 | g2 |
| 3 | 2022-2 | 3 | g1 |
| 4 | 2022-2 | 4 | g1 |
| 5 | 2022-2 | 1 | g2 |
| 6 | 2022-3 | 2 | g3 |

I would like do create a table which shows the cumulative sum over time by each group, the group and the date.

Expected result:

| date | sum_amount | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-1 | 2 | g1 |
| 2022-1 | 5 | g2 |
| 2022-2 | 9 | g1 |
| 2022-2 | 6 | g2 |
| 2022-3 | 2 | g3 |

I'm using the following query to get the total cumulative sum for all groups:

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') month,
       sum(sum(amount))over(order by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')) sum_amount
from table
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')
order by 1
```

I tried to simply add the 'group' to this query, like this:

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') month,
       sum(sum(amount))over(order by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM'), group) sum_amount,
       group
from table
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM'), group
order by 1
```

But the problem is that this last query still calculates the total amout and not for each individual group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery to first aggregate per month and group. Then, the analytic `SUM()` can do the job. For example:

```
select dt, sum(a) over(partition by grp order by dt) as amt, grp
from (
  select dt, sum(amount) as a, grp
  from t
  group by dt, grp
) x
order by dt, grp
```

Result:

```
 DT      AMT  GRP 
 ------- ---- --- 
 2022-1  2    g1  
 2022-1  5    g2  
 2022-2  9    g1  
 2022-2  6    g2  
 2022-3  2    g3
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=945302062b9ad04fa824f3ef9e5ef652).

Answer (score 0):

select distinct date, sum(amount) over(partition by group order by date) as sum_amount, group
From table
order by date, group